# Old sandbox paypal account - recurring payments IPNs

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I cannot recover my old sandbox account as I do not remember the password. I do not care too much about the test account but would like to stop the IPNs (recurring payments) that keep coming to my test website.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.  One would be to change the path to your IPN script.  If you do not have any other valid/live IPN's being sent to it.  Change the path name, rename the file or etc.  This will cause the IPN's to faile.  Option 2, if you can provide me with the test sandbox email address for the account you have this setup on, I can take a look at the account and disable it from my side.

Comment: Thanks. The website has already been moved a few weeks ago. I would very much like to have the account disabled. Do you mind if I contact you offline on your skype account for that purpose? (Am not too keen on giving away my email address). Thanks again.

Comment: You can either email the details to StackOverFlow@paypal.com or you can open up a ticket with MTS at www.paypal.com/mts and provide the details in the ticket.  Then just reply back here with the ticket number and I will pick it up and take a look.  Either way is fine.